# How to use the "find" command to find files bigger than 1MB, and execute a chosen command on each file?

Tags: bash, scripts, find

I'm trying to write a script that will find all files bigger than 1MB, and one at a time ask the user what to do with each file: delete, compress, or skip.

So far this is what I have got:

`find / -type f -size +1000000c -exec echo "File found: " {} \; -exec echo "(D)elete, (C)ompress, or (S)kip: " \;`

What would happen next is that the user would input either D, C, or S, and the corresponding command would be executed on the file, but I have no idea how to both read user input and implement an "if" loop during the execution of the "find" command.

I realise this is a very beginner question, but I couldn't find any answer. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1. create a shell script (remember to make it executable) to which you pass the path of a file.  The shell script will then present the user with the options and  perform the corresponding action
2. invoke the shell script from your find command

```
find / -type f -size +1000000c -exec your-shell-script {} \;
```

Example shell script (not a comprehensive solution)

```
#!/bin/bash

TargetFile="$1"
shift

if [ -z "$TargetFile" ]; then
    echo "$0 must be invoked with a path to a file" >&2
    exit 1
fi

while true; do
    echo "(D)elete, (C)ompress, or (S)kip: $TargetFile" >&2

    # Obtain a single keypress.
    # You may wish to tune this behaviour e.g. remove the n1 option
    read -rsn1 Action 

    # The case statement accepts the upper or lower case letters
    # Tune to taste
    case "$Action" in
    D|d)
      echo "Deletion Logic"
      ;;
    S|s)
      echo "Skip Logic"
      break
      ;;
    C|c)
      echo "Compression Logic"
      ;;
    *)
      continue
      ;;
   esac
   break
done

exit
```

I'll leave the finer implementation details to you :)